# PySide - How to dynamically update a string value based on QLineEdit Text value?

Tags: pyqt4, pyside

How do I make my string dynamically updated every time the Text value from a QLineEdit changes? I tried using signals and slots and works fine with QLabel, but not string.

```
self.lnEditCurrentNS = QtGui.QLineEdit(self) # This is my QLineEdit

my_string = 'none'
self.lnEditCurrentNS.textChanged.connect(self.onSelectedValue)

def onSelectedValue(self):
    selectedValue = self.txtEditCurrentNS.displayText()
    my_string = selectedValue
```

Let's say currently lnEditCurrentNS = 'none', then its changed to 'hello'. The value of my_string remains as 'none' instead of getting updated to 'hello'.

The value of lnEditCurrentNS got updated dynamically when the current index of a combobox I have is changed (combobox = 'hello', lnEditCurrentNS = 'hello')

I'm not very familiar with PySide/PyQt so any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `my_string` outside the `onSelectedValue`, you assigned a value inside `onSelectedValue`. Now if you use `my_string` outside the `onSelectedValue`, it won't give the lineEdit's text.

You can do the following trick:

```
self.my_string = 'None'
...

def onSelectedValue(self):
    self.my_string = self.textEditCurrentNS.text()
```

You can now use `self.my_string` at any place in the code to have the current text of the lineEdit.

Comment: I have tried this before, but it doesn't work too. I'm not sure what did I do wrongly. Funny when I switch to label it works instantly. But then I can't use label because I'm trying to display the contents of tuple based on a given key.

Comment: You are assigning lineEdit's text to `my_string` inside `onSelectedValue`, which is a local variable and can't be used anywhere outside this method. Can you show the code where and in which method you are using `my_string`. I mean where (in which method) did you try to print or use the value of `my_string`?

Comment: I have a class called `class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget)` and within the class i have `def __init__(self):`,`def initUI(self):`,`def onSelectedValue(self):` and several other methods.  

I declared `self.my_string` in `initUI` and assigned `self.mY_string = self.txtEditCurrentNS.text()` in `onSelectedValue`  

If it helps, I'm trying to achieve something like this:  

**Example**
dict = { 'keyA':('value1','value2') }  

In combobox, I have all keys listed. Thus when that key is selected, I want to display all of the elements inside the tuple in a listbox. Any suggestion?